# Function satisfying the relation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-(e^{-x}-1)(e^{-y}-1)+1$

Tags: integration, limits

Let f be the differentiable function satisfying the relation  $f\left( {x + y} \right) = f\left( x \right) + f\left( y \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - y}} - 1} \right) + 1$; $\forall x,y \in R$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f'\left( {1 + h} \right) + f\left( h \right) - {e^{ - 1}}}}{h}$ exist. The value of $\int\limits_0^1 {f\left( x \right)dx}  = \_\_\_\_\_\_\_$.

My approach is as follow

$f\left( {x + y} \right) = f\left( x \right) + f\left( y \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - y}} - 1} \right) + 1$

$\Rightarrow f\left( {x + y} \right) - f\left( x \right) = f\left( y \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - y}} - 1} \right) + 1$

$ \Rightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + y} \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( y \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - y}} - 1} \right) + 1}}{h}$

$ \Rightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + y} \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( y \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - y}} - 1} \right) + 1}}{h}$

y=h

$ \Rightarrow f'\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + h} \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( h \right) - \left( {{e^{ - x}} - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{ - h}} - 1} \right) + 1}}{h}$

How will I proceed from here

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+e^{-x}$. Then given equation reduces to  Cauchy's equation $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. If $f$ is assumed to be continuous (or at least measurable) then $g(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$ and $f(x)=-e^{-x}+cx$.

The given limit exists if and only if $c=1$ and this gives $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx=\frac 1 e-\frac 1  2$.

Comment: You still have to correct the sign in your last formula.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $g(x) = f(x) + e^{-x}$, then the equation becomes $g(x + y) = g(x) + g(y)$.

It is well-known that [all continuous solutions to that equation are linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), i.e. there exists $c$ such that $f(x) = cx$.

The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your method $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)+1 -(e^{-x}-1)(e^{-h}-1))}{h}$$ for derivative to exist $f(0)=-1$ hence by L-Hospitals rule $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)+1}{h}-\lim_{h\to 0}(e^{-x}-1)\frac{(e^{-h}-1)}{h}$$
$$f'(x)=f'(0)+e^{-x}-1=e^{-x}+C\Rightarrow f(x)=-e^{-x}+Cx$$
Now for the given limit to exist $f'(1)+f(0)=e^{-1}$...hence find $C$...